# How to add digital signature to pdf

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm using MPDF library to generate pdf documents, Now I want to add digital signature extension with .pfx file into the pdf document. I searched over the internet most of the suggestion are showing as TCPDF, I don't want to use the TCPDF library. I want to continue with MPDF library for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

mPDF does not support signing documents yet, so you will have to use another solution - either switching libraries, or appending a step to your PDF generation process.

There is an open feature request https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/389
and a similar SO request [add Digital Signature using mPDF object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848211/add-digital-signature-using-mpdf-object)